# DLL dependency to static library

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll, cmake, linker

I currently build a purely **static** library `MainLib` for our customers that contains all symbols so that they can intrgrate it into their program. For several reasons, I now need to deliver **a DLL version** of `MainLib` that contains parts of the symbols **alongside a static library** `FeatureLib` that contains the remaining symbols. One reason is that we want to avoid bad guys using our software by simply stealing the DLL that is provided via the program of our customer. This wouldn't work if parts of the symbols are integrated within the calling software via a **static library**. The user of the package shall only be able to use the DLL if he added the symbols of `FeatureLib` into his application.

For Linux, I can make this work like a charm,i.e. the symbol `doFeature()` is not within `libMainLib.so`, but I don't succeed on this for Windows.

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(MainLib)

add_library(FeatureLib STATIC src/FeatureLib.c)
target_include_directories(FeatureLib PUBLIC include
                                      PRIVATE src)

add_library(MainLib SHARED src/MainLib.c)
target_include_directories(MainLib PUBLIC include
                                   PRIVATE src)

# I don't want to include symbols from FeatureLib into shared MainLib
#target_link_libraries(MainLib PRIVATE FeatureLib)

add_executable(MainLibDemo src/demo.c)
target_link_libraries(MainLibDemo MainLib FeatureLib) #resolve symbol doFeature()
```

`FeatureLib.h`:

```
extern int doFeature(int input);
```

`MainLib.h`:

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) int MainLib(int input);
```

`FeatureLib.c`:

```
#include "FeatureLib.h"
int doFeature(int input) {return 4;}
```

`MainLib.c`:

```
#include "FeatureLib.h"
#include "MainLib.h"

__declspec(dllexport) int MainLib(int input)
{
  if (input > 2) {
    return doFeature(input);
  } else {
    return doFeature(0);
  }
}
```

`demo.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "MainLib.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if(argc > 1)
    return MainLib(atoi(argv[1]));
  else
    return 0;
}
```

With this, I get the following compilation error:

```
"C:\Daten\tmp\DemoProject\simple\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (Standardziel) (1) ->
"C:\Daten\tmp\DemoProject\simple\build\MainLib.vcxproj" (Standardziel) (4) ->
(Link Ziel) ->
  MainLib.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _doFeature referenced in function _MainLib [C:\Daten\tmp\DemoProject\simple\build\MainLib.vcxproj]
  C:\Daten\tmp\DemoProject\simple\build\Debug\MainLib.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [C:\Daten\tmp\DemoProject\simple\build\MainLib.vcxproj]

    0 Warnung(en)
    2 Fehler
```

Is this even possible with Windows? What do I have to do to make it work and how can I verify it other than not linking `FeatureLib` to `MainLibDemo`. Any ideas are very welcome.

Kind regards,
Florian

Comment: any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You would need, at least, to edit your post to show what "I don't succeed on this for Windows" means.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Mike. I added the build error message to the description.

Comment: There is an inconsistency in your question. Your `CMakeLists.txt` says that
`MainLib` is built from C++ source `src/MainLib.cpp`, but later you say that
`doFeature` is called in C source `MainLib.c` and the error message indicates that
`MainLib.obj` was compiled from C, not C++, because the unresolved reference
to `_doFeature` has not been name-mangled. Best if you provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks Mike for your feedback. I updated the description so it only contains C code and is complete. I hope it now meets the requirements for being Minimal, Complete and Verifiable. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: *One reason is that we want to avoid bad guys using our software by simply stealing the DLL.* **If** such "bad guys" want it (why do you think they'd bother?), they'll get it if you distribute it. Either you distribute your compiled code or you don't.  If you distribute it, the format doesn't matter.  Just try running various incantations of `nm` or even a simple `strings -a` against your "safe" Linux libraries...

Comment: True, but we assume it is harder to extract static library code from within our customers software than copying dlls.

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it under Linux will not work under Windows
because dynamic linking works differently here.
Here is one strategy that could work.

In `MainLib.dll` code, instead of directly calling `doFeature`
you need to define a global pointer variable of proper function
pointer type and use it to call the function.
This will allow to build `MainLib.dll` without errors.

Now you need to set this pointer variable. One way would be:

- Add exported function to `MainLib.dll` that takes pointers
  to all functions that the DLL needs from the executable.
- In `FeatureLib.lib` code add an initialisation function
  that the application will need to call before using
  your DLL which will pass pointers to its peers to the DLL.

This is basically the way most programs with plugins use to
give the plugins access to their facilities.

Another way would be to (Warning! I have not tested this specific
solution):

- Declare the functions in `FeatureLib.lib` as exported
  with `__declspec(dllexport)`. This way they will be exported
  *from executable.*
- In `MainLib.dll` before first using the pointers use
  `GetModuleHandle` and `GetProcAddress` to obtain the pointers.
  It would best be done in some initialisation function for the
  library. Otherwise you need to take care to avoid race conditions.

Hope this will help.
Though I do not think your copy protection scheme will work.
Andrew Henle is right in his comment: it is not hard
to extract the needed code from one executable and include it
in another.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my need is to deliver a DLL alongside a static library to avoid that thieves can grab the DLL and use it by inspecting the EXPORTS from them. If some parts of the library are distributed to our customers via static library, thieves can not make use of the DLL which is missing those symbols.